# Pagination in a rdlc report

Tags: c#

How can I set the pagination or the number of items being displayed in a single page? Suppose there are 1000 items and at each page I want to show 100 and use a next button to navigate to the next page . How can I be able to do that, Please discuss it in c# context .
  Thank You.

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution for this problem. I face same here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using PageBreaks.

From MSDN:

Page Breaks

> In some reports, you may want to place
>   a page break at the end of a specified
>   number of rows instead of, or in
>   addition to, on groups or report
>   items. To do this, create a group in a
>   data region (typically a group
>   immediately outside the detail), add a
>   page break to the group, and then add
>   a group expression to group by a
>   specified number of rows.
>
> The following expression, when placed
>   in the group expression, assigns a
>   number to each set of 25 rows. When a
>   page break is defined for the group,
>   this results in a page break every 25
>   rows.

```
  =Int((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/25)
```

Taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251668(VS.80).aspx

Comment: You need to specify the code in a group expression.  Here is how you do this...  First, select the Table that is generating the results.  Right-click on the ROW (by selecting the Gray row box that appears on the left side of the table) and select EDIT GROUP.  Add the expression in the list =Int((RowNumber(Nothing)-1/100)